# How do I map tables to Java objects

Tags: java, mybatis

Take an example i have three tables like this.
[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iryp6.png)
How cloud i map the third table to java object.

```java
class StudentCourse{
    Student student;
    Course course;
    Double score;
}
```

or

```java
class StudentCourse{
    Long studentId;
    Long courseId;
    Double score;
}
```

if i use the first one, after i update some datas in databse such as student informations.The next time i query StudentCourse from database(I use mybatis) will the cache cause the incorrect data?
if i use the second one, if i want to list student's course scores,i have to first query the list of StudentCourse and then query the course's information from database through courseId, for each result i need additional queries. I think that will reduce the efficiency of the program.
Is there another way to solve this problem?

For the  first one.
The second time mybatis do query, if the data hasn't been updated yet, it will get result from cache.

```java
    private <E> List<E> queryFromDatabase(MappedStatement ms, Object parameter, RowBounds rowBounds, ResultHandler resultHandler, CacheKey key, BoundSql boundSql) throws SQLException {
        this.localCache.putObject(key, ExecutionPlaceholder.EXECUTION_PLACEHOLDER);

        List list;
        try {
            list = this.doQuery(ms, parameter, rowBounds, resultHandler, boundSql);
        } finally {
            this.localCache.removeObject(key);
        }

        this.localCache.putObject(key, list);
        if (ms.getStatementType() == StatementType.CALLABLE) {
            this.localOutputParameterCache.putObject(key, parameter);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

If i have an resultMap like this

```xml
    <resultMap id="studentcourse" type="StudentCourse">
        <association property="student" resultMap="Student" />
        <association property="course" resultMap="Course"/>
        <result property="score" column="score"/>
    </resultMap>
```

At first i get an StudentCourse object from database, and the localCache cache the object.And then i update the Course in StudentCourse(change  the database record).The second time i get the some StudentCourse it will return an result from localcache.So the course information in StudentCourse is dirty data.How to deal with it if i choose the first one.

Comment: The second one is a better option since one student can have multiple course, and one course can have multiple students. Either way to load the Student object, you will need to query the database, so atleast using the second option, you only query the student or course table as needed.

Comment: But if in this way, for every StudentCourse i have to query it's Course information.And If there are a lot of records in the databse.A large number of queries can reduce the efficiency of the program.Or should i put all courseId in an array, and query like this?`select * from course where id in (1,2)`

Comment: I think the answer might be dictated by how you use the data, and therefore how you will be accessing the data in the database.  If you want to do a single query that returns information about all three of these objects, either for one `StudentCourse` or for many, then is there a way to map that data to the second option, or only to the first option where you're ultimately creating just a single object per row in the result?  If MyBatis can somehow create three independent objects from one query, then you have a choice.  If it can't, then isn't the first option the only option in that case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ideally you would use a class design that best models your domain and worry about mapping to a data store in a separate persistence layer. If you need to substantially change your model to allow the persistence layer to function then you need a new ORM! While I'm not familiar with mybatis I would hope it wouldn't create a new object each time the underlying data is changed.

The keys in the `course` and `student` tables act as foreign keys in the `student_course` table. Foreign keys are best represented as references in Java. To use the keys at the Java level forces an extra level of indirection and open you to integrity issues (e.g. if the foreign key changes).

So I would suggest:

```
class StudentCourse {
    private final Student student;
    private final Course course;
    private double score;
}
```

You could also consider having it inside one of the other classes - that might be more convenient depending on how the classes are used:

```
class Student {
    private final int id;
    private String name;
    private List<CourseScores> scores = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addCourseScore(Course course, double score) {
        scores.add(new CourseScore(course, score));
    }

    private record CourseScores(Course course, double score) { };
}
```

If your ORM doesn't resolve the keys for you (i.e. look up the referred object automatically when it retrieves data) then you'll need to do that yourself. It's a pretty simple object however:

```
class College {
    private Map<Integer,Student> students;
    private Map<Integer,Course> courses;
}
```

So the code to convert `student_course` data into the model above might look like:

```
ResultSet data;
while (!data.isAfterLast()) {
    Student student = college.getStudent(data.getInteger("student"));
    Course course = college.getCourse(data.getInteger("course"));
    double score = data.getDouble("score");
    student.addCourseScore(course, score);
    data.next();
}
```

Comment: So i should  query the Course information when i query  the course_student table?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'll add pointers on how to look up references